# building bytes in python

Tags: python-3.x, struct

input:

```
    print(struct.pack("b", 0)
    print(struct.pack("b", 0))
    print(struct.pack("I", 3))
    print(struct.pack("I", 0))
    print(struct.pack("I", 0))
    print((struct.pack('bbIII', 0, 0, 3, 0, 0)))
```

output:

```
   b'\x00'
   b'\x00'
   b'\x03\x00\x00\x00'
   b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
   b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
   b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Singed chars at the last row are returning 2bytes for some reason.I don't understand why the last bytearray is returning the longer value than what I expect, I would like to know a reason and a solution of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The struct is using the default `@` character to represent native size and alignment. This is what's causing the sizes to be different. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment).

You can instead use `=` which will use native byte order but standard size.

```py
print(struct.pack("=b", 0))
print(struct.pack("=bbIII", 0, 0, 3, 0, 0))
```

```py
b'\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' #14 bytes instead of 16
```

Comment: So in other words, the extra bytes are padding to meet some arbitrary alignment requirement.  Nice catch.